# Superposition of processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Considering the traffic on the road pictured in Figure 4.8.2, the following is known. The number of vehicles passing the point A in an hour follows the Poisson

[image]

distribution with mean 60; 20% of these vehicles are trucks. The number of vehicles passing B in an hour is also Poisson distributed with mean 80: 30% of these are trucks. In general, 10% of all vehicles stop at the restaurant. The number of persons in a truck is one; the number of passengers in a car is equal to 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 with respective probabilities 0.30, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10, and 0.10.

> Find the expected value E[Z] of the number of persons Z arriving at the restaurant within that one hour
>
> Compute $E[\alpha^{Z}]$ for $\alpha \in [0, 1]$.

My attempt

Taking the superposition of the processes $N_T(t)$ and $N_c(t)$, then

$\delta_T = ((60)(0.2)+(0.8)(0.3))0.1 = 3.6$ trucks per hour
$\delta_c = ((60)(0.8)+(0.8)(0.7))0.1 = 10.4$ cars per hour

From here, we have $E(N_T(1))=3.6$ and

$E(paseengers\ \ cars) = 1(0.4)(0.3)+2(10.4)(0.3)+3(10.4)(0.2)+4(10.4)(0.1)+5(10.4)(0.1) = 24.96$

Then, $E(Z)=28.56$. Is it correct?

Coud someone can helo for $b)$, I really can understand how to compute $E(\alpha^Z)$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1

**Note: I admit that my way of resolving this question may not necessarily be standard. But it is just to check the validity of OP's results.**

Well, first things first. Let's calculate the average number of people coming from a vehicle coming from each lane. We'll call $C$ the random variable containing the number of passengers coming out of a vehicle at the restaurant.

- When $k = 1$ we have both trucks and cars to consider. In that case, we have $P(C=1 \cap A) = 0.2 + 0.8 \times 0.3 = 0.44$ and $P(C=1 \cap B) = 0.3 + 0.7 \times 0.3 = 0.51$.
- When $k \geq 2$ we have only cars to consider. In that case, and only for $k = 2$ we have $P(C=2 \cap A) = 0.8 \times 0.3 = 0.24$ and $P(C=1 \cap B) = 0.7 \times 0.3 = 0.21$. I'll leave the rest of calculations to you.

So, we can now calculate $E[C\cap A]$ and $E[C\cap B]$. I'll leave the detail to you, but $E[C\cap A] = 2.12$ and $E[C\cap B] = 1.98$.

So, now that we've got that, we can say that the average number of people getting out of the vehicle when it comes from $A$ is 0.212 (Because of the 10% probability that the vehicle stops at the restaurant in the first place) and 0.198 for $B$.

But that's for one vehicle. In one hour, we've got on average 60 vehicles coming from $A$ and 80 from $B$. So, in that hour, that means that, **on average**, $60 \times 0.212 = 12.72 $ people will come from $A$ to the restaurant and $80 \times 0.198 = 15.84$ will come from $B$ to the restaurant.

Knowing vehicles can't come from another direction, it means that, on average, the restaurant will receive $12.72 + 15.84 = 28.56$ people.

My process is different, but it's still the same.

## Question 2

The transfer theorem indicates that $ E[\alpha^Z] = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \alpha^k P(Z=k)$. The most straightforward way to compute this sum would be to find a simple way to express $P(Z=k)$, and to bring ourselves to an expression that can be reduced.

I'll keep digging at this question.

Comment: Yes, b) it is complicated for me because A poisson process does not allow increments of more than 1 and by the nature of the variable there may be an increment of 5 at a time and I dont know how tocompute that expected value